# How to map values from multiple Pandas Dataframes based on certain conditions, including DateTime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, inner-join

I have 2 pandas dataframes, `df_pe` and `df_merged`. Both the dataframes have several rows, as well as several columns. Now, there are some specific things I would like to accomplish using these dataframes:

1. In `df_merged`, there is a column named `ST`, which contains timestamps of various events in format eg. `(2017-08-27 00:00:00)`. In `df_pe`, there are 2 columns `Ton` and `Toff` which contain the time when an event started and when and event ended. Eg. (`Ton` value for a random row: `2018-08-17 01:20:00` while `Toff` value `2018-08-17 02:30:00`).
2. Secondly, there is a column in `df_pe`, namely `EC`. I have another dataframe called `df_uniqueal`, which also has a column called `EC`. What I would like to do is:

   a. For all rows in `df_merged`, whenever the ST value is within the duration of `Ton` and `Toff` in the `df_pe`, create 2 new columns in `df_merged`: `EC` and `ED`. Append/Put the value of the `EC` from data frame `df_pe` into this new column, while, put the value of the dataframe `df_uniqueal` into the new column `ED` (which is eventually a mapped version of the `EC` in `df_pe` for obtaining `ED` in `df_uniqueal`). If none of the conditions matches/there are `NaN`s (missing values) left after this procedure, put the string `"NF"` into `df_merged`'s new `ED` column, while put the integer `0` into the `df_merged`'s new `EC` column.

I have explored SO and SE, but have not found anything substantial. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

This is my attempt at using `for` loops in Python for iterating over the dataframes for accomplishing the first condition but it runs forever (never ending) and I don't think this is the best possible way to accomplish this.

```
for i in range(len(df_merged)):
    for j in range(len(df_pe)):
        if df_pe.TOn[j] < df_merged.ST[i] < df_pe.TOff[j]:
            df_merged.EC[i] = df_pe.EC[j]
            df_merged.ED[i] = df_uniqueal.ED[df_processed.EC[j]]
        else:

            df_merged.EC[i] = 0
            df_merged.ED[i] = "NF"
```

**EDIT**
Please refer image for expected output and baby example of dataframes.[image: Expected Output and Baby Example]

The relevant columns are in bold (note the column numbers may differ, but the column names are same in this sample example).

Comment: This is hard to read and to understand. Include an example dataframe and an example expected output. We read data better than big blob of text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Erfan. I have now added the expected output and baby example. Cheers!

Comment: We cannot copy and paste pictures. Could you reproduce this data so we can copy them? Two things you can do: 1. `print()` them in your console and copy paste the output here or 2. see here how you can make dataframes in `pandas`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I am aware of how to create dataframes @Erfan. But the problem is that I need to work around this baby example which I mentioned here, as I cannot share the exact data.... I hope you understand the problem. I just want the suggestions as to the appropriate functions/methods in Python which can help with this, not the exact code, as I can do that myself please.

Comment: Do you expect only one row for the values of df_merged['ST'] to be inside df_pe['Ton'] and df_pe['Toff']?

Comment: @Cr1064 Sorry, no. I want to do this for all values in the dataframes, not just for one row. Thanks

Comment: @JChat Maybe I should rephrase, for a given row in df_merged['ST'] is there a chance that it lies between multiple rows in df_pe['Ton'] + df_pe['Toff']?

Comment: @Cr1064 you can think of df_merged as a large dataframe. It is possible that multiple rows of df_merged lie in the time intervals specified by Ton and Toff of df_pe but its also a possibility that none of the rows are in the interval/only a single row lies in the interval. But in that case I need to put NF and 0 as mentioned in the question.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly hopefully this will get you started.

```py
for i,val in df_merged['ST'].items():
    bool_idx = (df_pe['TOn']<val)&(val<df_pe['Toff'])
    if df_pe[bool_idx]['EC'].empty:
       df_merged.loc[i,'EC']=0
       df_merged.loc[i,'ED']="NF"
    else:
       value_from_df_pe = df_pe[bool_idx]['EC']
       df_merged.loc[i,'EC']= value_from_df_pe
       value_from_df_uniqueal = df_uniqueal[df_uniqueal['EC']==value_from_df_pe]['EC']
       df_merged.loc[i,'ED']= value_from_df_uniqueal
```

Please note I have note tested this code on any data.